# Create a linked list in C, after creating the array that holds the structure

Tags: c, linked-list

So what I want to do in brief is to create a structure, fill it in, and after that create a linked list. 
What I have done so far is this:
I have defined a linked list as below. Then I have filled it in with about 40 variables for PASSENGERS

```
typedef struct list1               
{
char var1[10];
char var2[10];     
struct list1 *next;
}LIST1;
```

Then I have dynamically allocated some memory to it (to host for example 40 structure items)

```
list  = (LIST1 *) malloc ((40)*sizeof(LIST1));
```

Filled it in with about 40 variables for PASSENGERS
by using for example

```
for (i=0;i<40;i++)
{
strcpy(list[i].var1,"AAAAAAAA");
strcpy(list[i].var2,"BBBBBBBB");
}
```

And what I need to do now is connect all these values, that are already there in a linked list, and print the result by using this linked list.

I am trying something like :

```
LINK1 *link, *start=NULL, *tmp;

for (i=0;i<40;i++)
    {link->next = NULL;
    if (start==NULL)
        start = link;
    else{
        tmp=start;
        while (tmp->next !=NULL) tmp=tmp->next;
        tmp->next=link;
        }

     }
```

and then to print the result of var1

```
while (tmp!=NULL)
{
    printf("%s",tmp->var1);
    tmp=tmp->next;
}
```

The code runs, but it doesn't print out anything. This is just a part of an exercise I am trying to solve, and I started with something simple to see how it works. I don't want to allocate memory only for one element at a time. I am asked to allocate all the memory necessary, fill in the structure and then create the linked list.

Comment: *"But it doesn't work out."* — How so? Please [edit] your question and be specific. Please also include any debugging you have done.

Comment: The daily linked list question finally arrived.

Comment: @SanchkeDellowar 10 in 4 days.

Comment: Please don't cast the result of `malloc`

Comment: In `link->next = NULL;` the local variable `LINK1 *link` is uninitialised.

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right way. You're not forced to use a `typedef`, you may use just a plain `struct` for your list and clearly use the name `node` so that you don't mix up nodes and lists. A node followed by a node is a list.

```
struct node {
    char * var1;
    char * var2;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Then you might use a helper function to push a node.

```
void pushvar1(struct node **head_ref, char *new_data) {
    struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->var1 = strdup(new_data);
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
}
```

And a function to print the nodes

```
void printListvar1(struct node *node) {
    while (node != NULL) {
        printf(" %s ", node->var1);
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

Now you're just a `main` function short of success.

```
int main() {
    struct node *head = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0;i<40;i++)
    {
        pushvar1(&head, "AAAAAAAA");
    }

    puts("Created Linked List: ");
    printListvar1(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Complete program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char *var1;
    char *var2;
    struct node *next;
};

void pushvar1(struct node **head_ref, char *new_data) {
    struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->var1 = strdup(new_data);
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
}

void printListvar1(struct node *node) {
    while (node != NULL) {
        printf(" %s ", node->var1);
        node = node->next;
    }
}
void freeList(struct node* head)
{
    struct node* tmp;

    while (head != NULL)
    {
        tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(tmp->var1);
        free(tmp);
    }

}
int main() {
    struct node *head = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        pushvar1(&head, "AAAAAAAA");
    }

    puts("Created Linked List: ");
    printListvar1(head);
    freeList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Test

```
./a.out 
Created Linked List: 
 AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAA
```

Comment: Thank you, it was very clear! ANd also helped me in getting a new idea for solving this exercise.Instead of converting the structure to a linked list, which is what I was thinking (which is obviously not a good idea), I think it is better to copy the values of this structure, that already holds some data,  to a similar structured - NEW linked list, by using the code you suggested with small modifications!

Comment: @baskon1 I'm glad you liked the answer. I think that C sometimes is easier than other languages because you can be concise with C and you're not forced to do encapsulation all the time as in Java.

Comment: @DacSaunders don't forget to free memory